# Adding mail header as column in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

I'd like to be able to display the contents of an email header (X-Spam-Score) as a column in the email list within Thunderbird.

This header is added by my mail providers Spam Assassin install, and I'd like to be able to sort mail with it.

I know how to *filter* mail using this header, but I'm trying to get it to display as a column , next to From, Subject, Date and so on.

Thunderbird V 17.0.7

Comment: Are you open to add-ons?

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem, as long as it does what I need. I did have a look for add ons, there are a few that add extra fields, but non give me the ability to either specify an email header as a column or add this specific header

Comment: I don't know if you've looked at this (or if you could adapt it) but the [spamness](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/spamness/eula/192592?src=dp-btn-primary) seems to add a column based on the score

Comment: @SeanCheshire , that looks quite interesting, it seems ot can be configured to display the score itself rather than it visualisation 'blob'

Comment: I tried the spammness extension. When I first added it i saw a few emails had values in the new column added, but now they are all blank again. so, this seems a possibly unreliable extension. It looks like it uses regex to scrape the information out of the headers, I wonder if this is heavily depended on the version of Spam Assassin in use.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this [columnswizard addon](http://micz.it/thunderdbird-addon-columnswizard/) for this and it works great.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This might work as a workaround, to show the X-Spam-Score header in the message headers:

1. Go into `Tools > Options > Advanced > General`, then click `Config`
   Editor.
2. Copy-paste `mailnews.headers.extraExpandedHeaders` into the `about:config` search bar.
3. Double-click and enter `X-Spam-Score` as value.
4. Close both windows and restart Thunderbird.

[source](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&p=9961313)

Comment: I'll try that, but that is not quite what I'm looking to do. I want to be able to sort emails in the folder based on this header value

Comment: If you want to add multiple headers, use a space as a separator. [source](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Custom_headers#Customize_what_headers_you_see)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution for now seems to be the creation of an extension. Here's a example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Thunderbird/Creating_a_Custom_Column